# How to export a profile in Toxic?

Tags: gnome, tox, toxic

I recently installed the [Tox client Toxic](https://wiki.tox.chat/clients) and created an encrypted profile with it, however I now want to export my profile in order to import it into another Tox client, but after going through the `/help` section, I am not sure how to do this. It said for more information not covered in its built-in help section to go to its manpage, however after typing:

```
man toxic
```

This is the output:

```
No manual entry for toxic
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

So as I can't seem to find the manpage, nor any documentation documenting how to export a Toxic profile I am lost... So how do I export it? It says [here](https://wiki.tox.chat/clients) that there is a way.

I am running the latest version of Toxic and Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [tox wiki page](https://wiki.tox.chat/users/import_export), the profiles are stored in `~/.config/tox/` , specifically the file is `profile_toxic.tox`.  Exporting simply is a matter of copying that file and saving it. To import profile on another machine, simply copy over that file into the `~/.config/tox` directory, or use `toxic -f /path/to/saved/profile_toxic.tox`