# How to import a profile into qTox?

Tags: qtox, toxic

I have [exported my Toxic profile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717830/how-to-export-a-profile-in-toxic) and I now wish to import it into qTox, however there is no import button when launching qTox and on the [wiki](https://wiki.tox.chat/clients/qtox) it does say that qTox has `Semi` capabilities to do this, though it leaves a note:

> There was full support, but due changes ability to import through GUI
>   was lost. It's still possible to use profiles from other clients, but
>   there is no easy way of importing them.

So how do I import the toxic_profile.tox file that I have? And how does this process differ from importing a qTox profile into qTox?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: Did you ask @blade19... directly already? He's the resident Tox expert.

Comment: Just copy paste the profile folder into the qtox installation. At startup you get a message window asking which profile to load. Select load at startup, and your done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I did it, was to just copy the `tox` folder -  `~/.config/tox/` - save the folder in the cloud or USB drive, And after reinstalling your Ubuntu(/Linux) machine, or you have a new one, copy the same folder in the same directory(`~/.config/tox/`)

At startup you will get a message window asking which profile to load, select your profile name, and then check the 'Load at Startup' option.

---

According to the tox wiki - for now - this is the recommended workaround.

> "Importing through GUI was possible before, but due to a regression one has to do it manually now." - [users:import_export - Tox Wiki](https://wiki.tox.chat/users/import_export)

Comment: So why does it say that it's not possible through the GUI? Is that because you have to manually move the file there?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda According to the tox wiki: `Importing through GUI was possible before, but due to a regression one has to do it manually now.`.

Comment: Wonderful! :D This worked for me to use same user in dual-boot- Ubuntu & Kali, Thank you very much